# Call a java method with JMeter

Tags: java, jar, jmeter, beanshell

My problem is about JMeter and the BeanShell PostProcessor.

I have developped a Java project with Eclipse and exported that project in a jar. I have put this jar in /lib/ext folder of JMeter.

When I call `java -jar C:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-2.9\lib\ext\myJar.jar` everything works fine.

Now I want to call the method in my jar inside JMeter. Inside my Beanshell processor I put this code :

```
import bsh.LoadProperties;
import bsh.SSOTokenHelper;

LoadProperties loadProperties = new LoadProperties();
loadProperties.init();

result = SSOTokenHelper.getSecurityToken();
```

For information, it's the exact code that I have in my main class. But in the log file of Jmeter I have this message :

> jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import bsh.LoadProperties;
>   import bsh.SSOTokenHelper;  LoadProperties loadProper . . . '' :
>   Method Invocation SSOTokenHelper.getSecurityToken

I don't understand why it's working when I call my jar directly and why it's not working when i do the exact same thing by JMeter.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`bsh.SSOTokenHelper` isn't a real BeanShell class, according to the javadocs at http://www.beanshell.org/javadoc/index.html. You probably need to correct the import, or if you've made up the `SSOTokenHelper` class, put it in a different package to avoid confusion and make sure its class is available to JMeter.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help.

I have made that class myself. I have changed the name of the package and put the new jar in /lib/ext folder of JMeter but there's still the same problem.

Comment: You should open up the jar you made (in a zip file viewer) and check you've got the directory structure correct. Look at the Java tutorial on jar files http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

Comment: When i call java-jar myJar.jar it works fine. My directory structure can be wrong ? I will take a loot a your link anyway ;)

I would like to know if there is some limitation by calling a jar with Beanshell (example : can't understand the generic type).

Comment: Try putting it in `lib` rather than `lib/ext` - see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath

Comment: Problem solved :) See my answer if you want to know where I was wrong